# Are there any plans to continue the story of The Guyver?

Tags: bio-booster-armor-guyver

The series *Bio-Booster Armor Guyver* is a *long* running manga series and franchise, that has been around since 1985.

[image: Bio-Booster Armor Guyver poster showing a character in the armour with mainly robotic features and overly exaggerated muscles with half of his human face showing]

It's an interesting franchise, combining sci-fi fantasy with themes of war, power, corruption, pre-destination, the purpose and nature of mankind, ancient aliens, corporate greed and conspiracies.

It's been so prevalent, that it has gotten 2 American movies made in the 1990s, one co-starring Mark Hamill, no fewer than 3 anime series, including a very well done one as late as 2005.

[image: Guyver: The Bioboosted Armor movie poster showing a male character straining and reaching to the side and the armour doing a similar thing silhouetted above and behind him]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

The manga on which it is based is supposedly still running, but no new chapters have been released to my knowledge recently.

[image: The Guyver movie poster showing Mark Hamill as the main character with half of his face covered with the armour; the bottom half shows a group of humanoid aliens walking in formation] [image: Guyver: Dark Hero movie poster showing the main character head to toe in the armour and a lightning strike in the background]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Does anyone know if there any plans to continue the franchise? If so, in what format?

Comment: If memory serves, the film was still in development hell

Comment: @Valorum Wait, there's a new _movie_ planned? American, or Japanese? Live action, or CGI? What are the details?

Comment: There was a rapidly-produced TV sequel called [MacGyver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGyver_(1985_TV_series)), although it took the concept in a noticeably different direction.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite**stern look, eye twitch, yet trying not to laugh** ....you have no soul.

Answer (score 4):

I read years ago that the creator, Yoshiki Takaya, stopped writing and drawing Guyver to become a dentist in Japan.  Since then, the manga has been on hiatus.  However, a guy on change.org has a petition to get the rest of it released in English, and as of this morning (Monday, May 8th, 2023), pre-orders have begun for Takaya's new Guyver art collection book, the first Guyver work he has been involved with in years.  I don't know if this will lead to the series being finished, but maybe a glimmer of hope that Takaya will return to the Guyver one day soon:

[Yoshiki Takaya Art Collection Bio Booster Armor Guyver Illustration Chronicle Artbook](https://www.play-asia.com/yoshiki-takaya-art-collection-bio-booster-armor-guyver-illustrat/13/70g49f)

[Change.org Guyver Petition](https://www.change.org/p/guyver-bring-a-full-english-translation-to-western-audiences/w?source_location=petition_nav)

Comment: From what I remember, he was having health issues; that's why he stopped writing it. He even alluded to this in the manga itself, mirroring his own health through that of the character Arkenfel. If this new "glimmer of hope" you bring is true, then I'd be down to sign a petition to finish it out in 50 chapterss....or even _turn it over to another artist,_ and just have Takaya build the bible and plot line the story, leaving the new writer/artist to fill in the details while he works as a Co-editor capacity.